# Replace javascript confirm dialog box with jquery confirm dialog

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to write simple jquery confirm dialog with two buttons: delete and cancel. When dialog was written with javascript, everything worked well. Now  cancel button works but delete button does not delete anything and just cancels deletion. I want  commandname to call cmddelete property which will delete row.

I am using this example: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/616118/jQuery-confirmation-in-ASP-NET-GridView

```
Csharp code:
protected void RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            int rowIndex;
            switch (e.CommandName)
            {  
case "CmdDelete":
            rowIndex = (((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).Parent.Parent as GridViewRow).RowIndex;
            DeleteItem(ViewData.List[rowIndex].ID);

Gridview:
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="CmdDelete" 
Text="delete"  OnClientClick="javascript:return deleteItem(this.name);" ></asp:LinkButton>
```

Javascript code:

```
function deleteItem(CmdDelete)) {
    var dialogTitle = 'Message from the webpage';

    $("#deleteConfirmationDialog").html('<p><span class="ui-icon " + 
      "ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>" + 
      "Please click delete to confirm deletion.</p>');

    $("#deleteConfirmationDialog").dialog({
        title: dialogTitle,
        buttons: {
            "Delete": function () { __doPostBack(CmdDelete, ''); 
                      $(this).dialog("close"); },
            "Cancel": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
        }
    });


$('#deleteConfirmationDialog').dialog('open');
return false;
```

}